# find two equations for the tangent lines to the curve

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]So I have one answer but I can't figure out how to get the other answer so I was seeing if someone could help me out here.
Find equations of the tangent lines to the curve $\displaystyle y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ that are parallel to the line $x-2y=5$. Then it wants you to find $y=$ _______ (smaller $y$-intercept) and $y=$ ________ (larger $y$-intercept). I have found the larger $y$-intercept which is $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{7}{2}$, but I'm not sure how I am supposed to find the smaller $y$-intercept.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A $y$-intercept is not an equation, it is a real number: the value of $y$ for a point on the curve on the $y$-axis.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I added the picture that's exactly how the question is displayed.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I know I need to use the quotient rule and finding the derivative is the slope. I just don't know how you are supposed to get two equations from it.

Comment: I see. You do not want the $y$-intercept, you want the equation that has the lower $y$-intercept. See my answer for more comments.

Answer (score 1):

The general method is to use the quotient rule to find the slope of the tangent line at any given $x$, and to solve for $x$ when that slope equals the slope of your given line $x-2y=5$. The resulting equation is a quadratic equation that has two roots. For each of those $x$'s you find the corresponding $y$ and use the point-slope form of a line to get the equation of the two desired tangent lines.

You got the one correct answer, so you got one of the $x$'s, but apparently you missed the other $x$. Did you remember to add a $\pm$ when you solved the quadratic equation? The answer you got comes from the $+$: now use a $-$ to find the other $x$.

Comment: yes I did but my other x was 1. So when you plug that in it is 0/2. Or is it not 1?

Comment: Yes, the other $x$ is $1$. Plug that into the original equation and you get $y=0$. Use the resulting point $(1,0)$ in the point-slope form of a line to get the other desired tangent line.

Comment: ok thank you I got it now.